# Quickest Way to create Face and Edge objects in Sketchup

Tags: ruby, graphics, 3d, sketchup

I have to render a mesh of a few thousand polygons in Google Sketchup. I find that `add_face` tends to get slower as the number of faces in the model increases. I believe this to be due to some edge detection algorithm that Sketchup is running behind the scenes. Hopefully, there should be some way to suppress this edge detection or other processing that Sketchup is doing till all faces have been added to the model.

I found `add_faces_from_mesh` and `fill_from_mesh` to be much faster but I end up with a mesh consisting of `Surface` instances instead of the `Face` and `Edge` objects I am looking for.

So, what is the fastest way to generate a model consisting of `Face` and `Edge` objects in Sketchup? Is there a way to generate `Edge` and `Face` objects from a `Surface` object?

**Update:** I just read [here](http://code.google.com/apis/sketchup/docs/releases.html) that using `Model::start_transaction` and `Model::commit_transaction` can be used to speed things up but I found that the improvements are not very significant. Anything else I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found `add_faces_from_mesh` and
>   `fill_from_mesh` to be much faster but I
>   end up with a mesh consisting of
>   `Surface` instances instead of the `Face`
>   and `Edge` objects I am looking for.

Calling `add_faces_from_mesh` or `fill_from_mesh` with the `smooth_flags` parameter explicitly set to zero correctly constructs `Face` and `Edge` objects. [Sketchup Documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/sketchup/docs/ourdoc/entities.html) claims that `smooth_flags` defaults to zero... my trials show otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify - `add_faces_from_mesh` and `fill_from_mesh` do add Edges and Faces - however, the default behaviour is to create a mesh with soft and smooth edges. When you have a set of Faces connected by Soft edges they will be treated as a surface by SketchUp and Entity Info window will say "Surface" when you select them.
However - internally it's still just a set of edges and faces - SketchUp has no Surface entity.

As for `Model::start_transaction` - you must specify true for the second `disable_ui` argument in order to see any speed gains. But as you have noticed, SU is very slow to add entities - the more there is in the entities collection you add to the slower it gets. The absolute fastest way to add entities is `fill_from_mesh`.